# How to npm install with git-bash/mingw32 on win7

Tags: npm, mingw32, git-bash

I am using git-bash/mingw32 on win7. I am trying to install npm:

```
$ npm install
sh: npm: command not found.
```

Git-bash is working normally and is installed correctly. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a couple of reasons for this behaviour:

1) npm not installed

2) npm not in %PATH%

You can add npm to %PATH% by running cmd (win+r -> cmd) as administrator and execute:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\here\is\path\to\npm\dir
```

After that — try run npm again.

Answer (score 1):

while installing node.js when click the set path option.
check system environment path.

```
# echo $PATH
```

and see if there is npm/node in it. if not, added them to the system environment.

```
# set PATH=%PATH%;d:/node/;
```

mostly reinstall node check the right option will fix this, and update dev env btw.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason (if node was installed by Visual Studio): a missing `npm` bash script.

There is an `npm.cmd` bath file in the path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\npm.cmd
```

But `git bash` wont run `.cmd` files. So you need to create a bash script for npm.

Create the following file named `npm` in your node folder: (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\`)

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=`dirname "$0"`

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```