# Applications from PATH are not available in mingw64 shell

Tags: mingw, msys2

Based on what I have read, people use things like npm or python within the mingw64 shell. It doesn't sound like they're installing it within its context though.

Take e.g. this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26319712/5040168

Or this here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/962#issuecomment-40845394

Well, I have npm installed and am able to run it from anywhere in a Windows command prompt. But in the mingw64 shell, I get:

```
# npm install 
bash: npm: command not found

# which npm
which: no npm in (/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/)
```

Answer (score 0):

The MSYS2 environment is designed to change the PATH environment variable so that it can be more isolated from all the programs and DLLs you might have installed on your computer.  When I want to run an external program, I usually write a little shell script like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/c/Program\ Files/npm/bin
```

(Note: I don't know the path to the NPM binaries on your computer so the path I wrote above is made up.  You will need to edit the file above to have the correct path(s) to the particular programs you want to run.  Separate multiple paths with colons.  Use the POSIX-style paths that start with `/`.)

Suppose the name of that shell script is `use_npm.sh`.  Then if you want to use NPM, you would first run this in my MSYS2 shell:

```
source use_npm.sh
```

After doing that, the NPM binaries would be on your path and you could run them conveniently by just typing their names.  If you start a new shell, you would have to run the script again.